# STL and GoogleTest?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stl, googletest

Does anyone know how to set up STL and Google Test on Visual Studio ? (I'm using Visual C++ Express 10)

I found a tutorial to set up Google Test (http://blog.feabhas.com/2012/03/setting-up-googletest-with-visual-c-2010-express-edition/) and another one for STL (http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-win.html), and I can set up Google Test without a problem (with "Runtime Library" set to "Multithreaded Debug (/MTd)"); for STL I need to change my "Runtime Library" option to "Multithreaded DLL Debug (/MDd)". If I try setting up both, I end up with lots of linker errors (LNK2005, etc.)

I've looked online for a while, and it seems like there's definitely a problem with this "Runtime Library" option, but I can't figure out why! Anyone would be kind enough to explain what I (or those tutorials) am doing wrong? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Okay, I finally found it. The mistake I made was during the NTL build; I thought that selecting "static library" would ensure a /MTd mode (for some reason), but when I checked, /MDd was enabled instead. One library exclusion later, everything was working perfectly!